# Cloning Rows of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and i am cloning rows to add a new row. But i don't seems to understand why its not working for me.Its just refreshing the page every time i click Add Row button. Also it would be very helpful if anyone can provide me code to increase the `<td id>` with every cloned row.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks

```js
$('.io').on('submit click change', eventHandler);

let counter = 0;

function eventHandler(event) {
  let eType = event.type;
  let eNode = event.target;

  switch (eType) {
    case 'submit':
      let clone = $('.grid tr:first-child').clone(true, true);
      $('.grid').append(clone);
      clone.find('.data').each(function(i) {
        this.disabled = true;
        this.value = '';
      });
      counter++;
      clone[0].id = `row${counter}`;
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;

    case 'click':
      if ($(eNode).hasClass('del')) {
        let row = $(eNode).closest('tr');
        if (row.index() !== 0) {
          row.remove();
        }
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;

    case 'change':
      if ($(eNode).hasClass('type')) {
        let row = $(eNode).closest('tr');
        let pick = eNode.value !== "X" ? true : false;
        row.find('.data').each(function(i) {
          this.disabled = !pick;
          this.value = '';
        });
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;

    default:
      event.stopPropagation();
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Arial
}

form {
  //margin: 10px auto
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#theader {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

th:first-of-type {
  width: 30%
}

th:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 35%
}

th:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 35%
}

th:last-of-type {
  width: 30%
}

td {
  padding: 0 8px
}

select,
textarea,
button {
  display: block;
  min-width: 97%;
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  font-size: initial;
}

select {
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='io' action="internet" method="post" name="frmmain" id="idfrmmain" >
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Links</th>
      <th>Desciption</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th><button>Add Row</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='grid'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class='type'>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/qlwidgetresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description" />
            <option value="#{description}">
              <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </option>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><textarea class='desc data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class='img data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class='url data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: First there is no event handler bound to the `add row` button. Secondly, why do you have one 'god' event handler on the `.io` element (which isn't shown in the HTML) that handles multiple different events? If you're doing it due to the dynamic elements then there are far better ways.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad.I have update the code.Everything is under a ```<form>```

Comment: Thank you for updating. The issue is because by default button elements are `type="submit"` you need to add `type="button"` to the add row button. Also note that you *really* need to restructure your JS to use individual delegated event handlers

Comment: I gave the ```<type="button">``` but it still doesn't seems to be working

Comment: There's not much we can really do to debug any further than that as the code works fine in the snippet in the question

Answer (score 0):

A `<button>` with no type= property specified is by default a "submit" type button. That's why you'll often see the odd-looking `<button type="button">`. This is likely why your page is refreshing, although you *usually* see that behavior when the button is inside of a form. Perhaps that form tag is just not visible in your HTML excerpt.

As @Rory McCrossan mentioned, you have one event handler, presumably tied to a high level item in your HTML (DOM), and then inside of it you are using a switch statement to determine what was actually clicked. If you don't have a good reason for this, it makes more sense to tie the event handlers to the specific elements they relate to. The way you have it may *work* but you're making but it's a lot less clean, more error-prone, and harder to work with this way.

If it were me, I'd set it up like this for your DOM:

```
 <th><button type="button" class="js-add-row">Add Row</button></th>
```

Then in your JS:

```
var rowCount = 1;
$( '.js-add-row' ).on('click', function(){
    const template = `<tr class="row-${rowCount}"> ... </tr>`;
    $( this ).closest( 'table' ).find( 'tbody' ).append(template);
    rowCount++;
});
```

Obviously you'd want to put in your whole template there. Instead of storing the template in JS, you could just clone the row that's out there, but that only works if you don't want to let the user delete all the rows. Or, sometimes people will store this template in the DOM but hidden so that it's not a real row. Or as a data- element on one of the table elements. The best practice may depend on your use-case.

The `$( this ).closest( 'table' ).find( 'tbody' )` part allows this to be more reusable. It's literally saying, from where this button was clicked, find the table it's inside of, then grab the tbody tag. You could have multiple tables with their own add buttons, and this would still work (in that case, the template would either need to be the same, or cloned from that first row).

You can see the advantage here of isolating this event handler. You have a clean function for doing this one thing. It's easy to find, easy to modify, easy to expand and copy.

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p1x0jsg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see if it could help.

```js
var cloneIndex = 1;

function clone(){
    $('.grid').children(".clonedInput:first-child").clone()
        .appendTo(".grid")
    //alert(cloneIndex)
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
        .on('click', '.addrow', clone)
    cloneIndex++;
}

$(".addrow").on("click", clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Links</th>
      <th>Desciption</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th><button type="button" class="addrow">Add Row</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='grid'>
    <tr id="clonedInput" class="clonedInput">
      <td>
        <select class='type'>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/qlwidgetresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description" />
            <option value="#{description}">
              <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </option>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><textarea class='desc data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class='img data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class='url data' rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to work, as for the question about setting the ids, you should change in your code:

```
clone[0].id = `row${counter}`;
```

with this:

```
$( clone[0] ).attr( 'id', `row${counter}`);
```